Obscure 1930s/40s thriller film about disappearing girls
I have been trying to identify a movie I saw once a long time ago on TV. It was a bit disturbing, black and white as far as I can remember. 
It focused around a young girl and a janitor of the apartments where she lived. I think she disappeared or young girls were disappearing. And excelsior (a packing material) was being routinely delivered to the flats. 
I think the janitor was a little 'simple' and he was killing the girl(s) and then covering them with the excelsior to protect them. 
I don't remember famous actors being in it, probably 1930/1940's English American film. 

I didn't put  ,disappearing girls, in the title myself as I am not sure that WAS the story.

You seem to mean the B&W cult thriller The Bad Seed from 1956, though you got the culprit wrong. It's about a seemingly perfect eight year old girl called Rhoda who turns out to be a heartless killer that murdered her classmate, among other victims. The only person that doesn't like her is Leroy, her building's simple-minded handyman. And excelsior does play a part later on. From IMDb:

Col. Penmark buys an expensive children's tea set for Rhoda and has it shipped to Rhoda, packed in excelsior. Rhoda goes out to play with it, and takes the packing material with her. Leroy sees her at play [...] Rhoda, for her part, gives Leroy the excelsior, saying that she knows about the bed of excelsior that Leroy has made for himself so that he can sleep on the job in the furnace room without being caught.

Based on a novel and a play of the same name. Here's a clip with Leroy, Rhoda and the excelsior:




thank you, thank you thank you!!!! I have been trying to find out what this film was called for years. Sorry I got the plot all wrong....but you managed to sort it any way.  It is over 40 Years since I last sat watching this...and it has stuck in my memory for  all that time. It really got under my skin. Many thanks again for solving my mystery
